# Getting number of rows of joined table by condition on another

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables products and products_to_categories

products contatins - product_id - name - price
(there are multiple products)
products_to_categories contains - product_id - category_id

all i need is number of rows selected when the conditions are

1. ONLY category with id "1" (category_id = '1');
2. ONLY products with price bigger then 100 (price > 100)

Any ideas?

Comment: It wasn't clear if you needed two counts, or just one count. The first query in my answer returns two different counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
p.product_id,
p.name,
p.price
from products p
inner join products_to_categories  pc on pc.product_id = p.product_id
where 
pc.category_id = 1
AND p.price > 100
```

Comment: Assuming you have more products than categories, MySQL will want to start with the products_to_categories table and join back to the products table, so ideal indexes would be `products(product_id, price)` and `products_to_categories(category_id)`. Or for a "covering index", use `products(product_id, price, name)`.

Comment: yes the join needs to be reversed and select from products_to_categories